# GLUT on Mac misses mUI

Tags: macos, glut

I'm trying to recompile an older unix OpenGL program on the mac. I came to the moment when most of dependencies are fulfilled. However, now I'm stuck on mUI extension of GLUT. I checked on my linux machine and there is a whole directory lib/mui with sources and include/mui with headers in glut-3.7. After compiling on linux I ended up with library files libglut.so.3.7 and libmui.a. The later one I linked to my program. I have found no trace of mui in GLUT.framework (OSX 10.9, Xcode 6.2; gcc/gfortran 5.0). Has anybody idea how to deal with this problem. I'm a bit afraid to compile glut myself, as I have no idea what will happen to my build if two different GLUTs exist. Should I just compile glut3.7 and statically link my code to this library?

Comment: You might be able to copy the mui source files (e.g., from https://github.com/markkilgard/glut) and compile just those into a `libmui.a` or `libmui.so` file. I think it should also be possible to compile a complete glut yourself and link that version to your program, without bumping into the default glut (ensuring your various paths are set up correctly). Overall though, mui appears to be really old and unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have compiled the libmui.a file using sources from glut-3.7.
I adapted the make file for linux. The main change was replacing OpenGL and Glut libraries to frameworks:

```
LIBRARIES   = -framework glui -framework glut -framework OpenGL  -lXmu -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

In *.C files I have replaced call to GLUT with:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
  #include <GLUT/glut.h>
#elif
  #include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

That was. I linked the libmui.a to my elderly application and it worked without any trouble.